# How to submit different scripts to the command line in python -

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I'm trying to loop through and submit shell scripts to the command line in python.  While this works for a given file:

```
os.system('qsub /directory/filename')
```

This does not:

```
file = '/directory/filename'
os.system('qsub file')
```

Python is interpreting the word 'file' instead of the object file.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = '/directory/filename'
os.system('qsub %s' % file)
```

You have to pass 'file' as an argument.

See http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html for some examples or http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting for the official docs.

Answer (score -1):

'qsub file' is a string use 'qsub ' + file

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
os.system('qsub %s' % file)
```